# SwipeRefreshLayout hides RecyclerView's upper part?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm beginner in android, and I don't know why this happens.
Without SwipeRefreshLayout the RecyclerView is fully visible, but with SwipeRefreshLayout, the first item isn't shown.

Maybe it's under the toolbar? (The hidden item exists, I checked it in numerous ways.)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/swipe_layout">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/MainRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

List:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="8dip"
    android:paddingBottom="8dip"
    android:paddingLeft="16dip"
    android:paddingRight="16dip"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:gravity="center">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/CharacterItemRankImageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/challengemode_medal_bronze"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/CharacterItemNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        tools:text="Name"/>


    <TextView android:id="@+id/CharacterItemPointsTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        tools:text="Points"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/CharacterItemRemoveButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_grey600_48dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Without Swipe]

[image: With Swipe]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using a CoordinatorLayout as root of your view. In that case, what is happenning is that the toolbar is being hidden by the first item of your RecyclerView.

To fix this issue, you just need to add the layout behavior to the SwipeRefreshLayout and remove from your RecyclerView.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/MainRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```